# How would one set up Xcode playgrounds to use a built framework in a stable way?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, swift-playground, audiokit

AudioKit has had playgrounds since they were introduced, and we made hundreds of them, but as of about Xcode 8, they have become difficult to use.  After about 4-5 playground views on average, Xcode will stop running any playgrounds and need to be restarted.

Here are the AudioKit's playground code:
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Playgrounds

as well as screen recordings of how they should work:
http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/

We basically use the set up as described in this blog to use the AudioKit framework in playgrounds:
https://m.pardel.net/using-3rd-party-frameworks-in-swift-playgrounds-fd415f6dba10

The playgrounds are equally unstable if we use playgrounds on the Xcodeproj itself as if we are using the framework file.

Does anybody have any clue as to what happened to make Xcode playgrounds unstable with frameworks or have any advice on how we could change our set up to make the playgrounds stable again?

AudioKit playgrounds were a major part of what makes AudioKit easy to use and the loss of them has weighed heavily on me, so I am happy to offer a bounty (my first one, so bear with me).

Comment: Try setting it not to automatically run?

Comment: Sorry, I could have added that to my description.  Setting it not automatically run does not seem to help much, if at all.  It gives the appearance of helping because you can at least visit more playground code, but as soon as you start running them, your days are numbered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not worked with Playgrounds in a while, but today I wanted to check some things out. I found Playgrounds hugely unstable, freezing up Xcode constantly. All I imported was `UIKit`, nothing fancy; just simple string parsing in a loop. Like yourself, I could get it to run a few times before needing to restart Xcode to regain responsiveness. This is in Xcode v9.3 (9E145).

Comment: Thanks for the commiseration, at least I know I'm not crazy.  I'll reward you with the bounty unless someone else comes in and swoops it up with something more.

Comment: Apple developer forums show others with the same issue
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97292
(plus many other similar threads)

Comment: I am seeing exactly this issue, just wanted to mention that. I hope we can find a solution (I too am looking) because it's such a shame not to be able to do justice to such a useful framework that you at AudioKit have all put so much time into...

Comment: Should also mention that I had previously ended up at the same apple link and had tried moving the folder to another location. Maybe it was improved but it's hard to be certain with this kind of varying behaviour...